# SQL Server to Netezza Data type equivalent

Tags: sql-server, database, types, migration, netezza

I need to convert these data types from SQL Server to Netezza:

- `decimal (38,5)`
- `Bit`
- `Varchar (50)`
- `Smallint`
- `datetime`

Can someone give me the equivalents on Netezza please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
|  Sql Server   |               Netezza               |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| Decimal(38,5) | Decimal(38,5)                       |
| Bit           | ByteInt (Boolean may be acceptable) |
| varchar(50)   | varchar(50)                         |
| smallint      | smallint                            |
| datetime      | timestamp (Date may be acceptable)  |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
```